Rutas dinamicas en next 13
hola buenas tengo el problema de que intento generar una ruta en una aplicación de blog no se cual sea el problema ya que me da un 404 al intentar acceder a la ruta deseada adjunto el codigo


<Link
          href={`/posts/${post.attributes.slug}`}
          key={post.id}



este link envuelve una card que se encuntra en el componente main en la carpeta components


import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { fetchPostBySlug } from "../../services/postsService";

const Slug = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;

  console.log(slug);

  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPost = async () => {
      const postData = await fetchPostBySlug(slug);
      console.log(postData);
      setPost(postData);
    };

    if (slug) {
      loadPost();
    }
  }, [slug]);

  if (!post) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <img src={post.image} alt={post.title} />
      <h3>{post.author}</h3>
      <h5>{post.date}</h5>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slug;



el componente slug es el que debería renderizar al abrir una card


export async function fetchPostBySlug(slug) {
  try {
    console.log("Fetching post by slug:", slug);
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/posts?slug=${slug}`);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Oops! Something went wrong");
    }
    const post = await res.json();
    return post;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching post by slug:", error);
    return null;
  }
}



el servicio

este es mi directorio

Es porque tu ruta /posts/[slug].js está dentro de pages de la siguiente manera: app/pages/posts/[slug].js en ese caso el Link tendría que ser en lugar de:
/posts/${post.attributes.slug}
especificar:
/pages/posts/${post.attributes.slug}
Si lo que querés es que se acceda a /posts/[slug].js tendrás que sacar la carpeta posts de la carpeta pages y posicionar posts dentro de app al mismo nivel de pages.

hola gracias por al ayuda pero no te entiendo blog es la carpeta principal del proyecto page tiene dentro posts y dentro el archivo que necesito que se acceda esto estaria asi blog/src/app/pages/posts/[slug].js en el link la ruta no se porque no accede ese seria el problema he probado lo que dices pero no funciona

hola, disculpa por la confusión, me refería a posts. ya edité la respuesta.

hola buenas gracias por tu respuesta el problema estaba en la ubicación de pages debia estar dentro de la carpeta src y como yo lo tenia era dentro de la carpeta app la ruta para que funcionen todo es src/pages y yo lo tenia asi src/app/pages por eso no funcionaba gracias por la ayuda bro @jonoise
